# How to add subdomain to dynamics 365 site

Tags: subdomain

I have a Microsoft Dynamics 365 application with a URL of the form https://mycompany.crm345.dynamics.com

My domain (https://www.mycompany.com) is managed by SquareSpace and I'd like to create a subdomain for the dynamics URL. Something like https://dynamics.mycompany.com

Following instructions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830915/how-to-add-a-subdomain-on-godaddy-on-azure-site) I added a CNAME for 'dynamics' with data 'mycompany.crm345.dynamics.com'. However I'm not in Azure so I can't add the domain on the Microsoft side.

How can I make this work?